# mySQL: Issue Using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to query 200 users, but don't know the exact `Subj_Id`s. Therefore, I cannot just query a range of `Subj_Ids` (though I know I want to start at 200), but need to set a limit on the range of `Subj_Ids` I'm querying. I tried:

```
SELECT *
    FROM session2
    WHERE Subj_Id > 200
    AND Subj_Id IN (
        SELECT Subj_Id
            FROM userdata
            WHERE `Primary Lang` != ''
            OR `Primary Lang` != '-'
            OR `Primary Lang` != '--'
    )
    LIMIT 200;
```

However, it only returns a handful of `Subj_Ids`. Is this an issue with my syntax, or with the db I'm using?

Comment: How many do you get if you don't specify the LIMIT 200?

Comment: I think the `WHERE Subj_Id > 200` seems odd. Do you really only want ones there the `Subj_Id` has a value of 201 or more?

Comment: Limit 200 doesn't mean it will return 200, if you where condition already filtered out most of users, then it should return a handful of users.

Comment: use  LIMIT 200, 5  to find is there any above 200 or try simply count(*)  :-)

Comment: The WHERE clause in the subquery is useless. If the language is `'-'` then it's not `''`. I think you should be using `AND`, not `OR`.

Comment: @ljh - Understood, but it shouldn't be filtering out nearly that many users. There are 1000s of users in the database.

Comment: @zod - I know that there are. There are 1000s of users.

Comment: @Barmar - I want to eliminate blanks, as well as dashes (sometimes 1 dash, sometimes 2). I thought I needed all of those.

Answer (score 0):

Select the users that you want in a subquery and then join back to get the sessions.

You are not clear about the format of the tables.  The following assumes that each table has a `user_id` and that `user_id`/`subj_id` define a session:

```
select s.*
from (SELECT user_id, max(subj_id) as maxsi
      FROM session2
      WHERE Subj_Id > 200 AND
            Subj_Id IN (SELECT Subj_Id FROM userdata WHERE `Primary Lang` not in ('', '-', '--') )
      group by user_id
      LIMIT 200
    ) u join
    session2 s
    on u.user_id = s.user_id and s.subj_id = maxsi
```

Comment: Sorry, user and subject are the same thing. I edited my question to reflect this. Userdata is another table, though, which is linked by `Subj_Id`. Is your answer still applicable?